# Mac nginx with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, nginx

I just installed nginx on my mac. Now I have no clue how to get RoR working with it. Before what I was doing was using Webrick and it was simple, i would just cd in my RoR dir and start the server. How can I do this with nginx?

Thanks

Comment: I compiled it from source then make/install

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to install and configure a local development stack consisting of Nginx, Passenger 4, and Ruby 2 on Mac OS X Lion. I documented the steps for my team in a blog post:

http://jrmyward.com/blog/posts/local-rails-development-with-nginx-passenger-4-and-ruby-2-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

I also develop locally on my mac on nginx. I used the following tutorial to get started: http://trevorturk.com/2010/09/22/passenger-with-nginx-on-mac-os-x-2nd-edition-2/

and of course the following railscasts helps a lot: http://railscasts.com/episodes/293-nginx-unicorn

Answer (score 0):

You can use passenger for working with ROR and Nginx
Steps for installing Ruby with rvm:

> 1)$ rvm list known
>
> 2)$ rvm install ruby-2.1.0      //use any latest version
>
> 3)$ rvm use 2.1.0 --default

Install Passenger:

> 1)$ sudo gem install passenger

Install Nginx:

> 1)$ brew update (I am using homebrew installer)
>
> 2)$ brew install nginx --with-passenger

Configure Nginx:

> 1)Open /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf file in any editor 
>   2)delete add server { } blocks and add following

```
server {
listen 3000;
server_name product.example.local;  
root /Users/username/code/product/public;
access_log /Users/username/code/product/log/nginx_access.log;
error_log /Users/username/code/product/log/nginx_error.log;
}
```

here

server_name will be '<'ror project name'>'.local

root will be '<'path to your ror project'>'/public

access_log will be '<'path to your ror project'>'/log/nginx_access.log

error_log will be '<'path to your ror project'>'log/nginx_error.log

In http{ block at first line add

```
http {
passenger_root /usr/local/opt/passenger;
passenger_ruby /Users/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby;
```

you can get passenger_root and passenger_ruby after you install nginx

$ brew install nginx --with-passenger
on command prompt

like

> To activate Phusion Passenger, add this to
>   /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf, inside the 'http' context:
>   passenger_root
>   /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini; 
>   passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

ok! you are done with installation just start nginx now

> $ sudo nginx

after that open browser and call

> http://localhost:3000

you can stop nginx with

> $ sudo nginx -s stop