# How to configure nginx configuration for rails on local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Normally running rails app on localhost:3000 via rails s command on port 3000.
For testing some specifics want to run it under a domain name on my OSX machine.
I have nginx installed on my Mac and want to know how to configure it to use  test.local to run  localhost:3000

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648587/mac-nginx-with-rails help

Answer (score 4):

1. Install nginx from brew

```
brew install nginx
```

2. Start nginx service

```
brew services start nginx
```

3. Visit `localhost:8080` to make sure nginx is running. You should see 'Welcome to nginx' page.
4. Create a configuration for test.localhost
   default nginx config directory with brew install is `/usr/local/etc/nginx/servers`

```
cd /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers
nano test
```

and copy the following

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name test.localhost;
  root /<path to project>/public;
  access_log /<path to project>/log/nginx_access.log;
  error_log /<path to project>/log/nginx_error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://tupstream;
  }
}

upstream tupstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

5. Now we need to restart nginx with `sudo` since we will be serving from `port 80`.

```
sudo brew services restart nginx
```

6. The next step is to make sure `test.localhost` points to 127.0.0.1
   Install dnsmasq via brew

```
brew install dnsmaq
```

7. Start the service with

```
sudo brew services start dnsmasq
```

8. Copy dnsmasq configuration file

```
cp $(brew list dnsmasq | grep /dnsmasq.conf$) /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf

## find the location of the file using
## brew list dnsmasq
## if the above doesn't work
```

9. To make sure .localhost TLD points 127.0.0.1

```
echo 'address=/.localhost/127.0.0.1' >> /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

10. Restart dnsmasq

```
sudo brew services restart dnsmasq
```

11. Edit your DNS servers and make sure 127.0.0.1 is the first entry.
    Settings -> Network -> WiFi -> Advanced -> DNS

[image: DNS server]

Make sure you are able to ping .localhost sites

```
ping test.localhost
PING test.localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
^C
--- test.localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.062/0.064/0.066/0.002 ms
```

Since the DNS has changed, make sure you can access remote sites too (`ping google.com`)

12. Start RoR server @ port 3000

```
rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

13. Take your browser and now enter `test.localhost`

[image]

Comment: If you get this error when you ping the .localhost site "ping: cannot resolve test.localhost: Unknown host" you need to update your host entry in /etc/hosts